"! HTTP 426 Upgrade Required." error when using httr2 req_perform
I'm trying to download a media file via a webservice internal to the place i work at that allows us to access a bunch of media. The link points to a specific media and downloads it.
It worked with no issues until a couple days ago, where the following code:
library(httr2)
library(here)
req <- request("link")
resp <- req_perform(d, path=here("test"))

returned the following error:
Error in `req_perform()`:
! HTTP 426 Upgrade Required.


i tried a random link (stackoverflow page) and it worked
i tried the same link via python, and it worked
i tried the same command lines on a different computer and it gave the same error message

I'm at loss here since I don't fully comprehend what kind of cooking happens when requesting.
Does anyone have an idea of how to fix it?
Thank you and have a nice day!
Cassandra

Try req_perform(d, path=here("test"), verbosity=3) to get more details about the request. There may be more info in the headers. Or try req |> req_error(is_error = \(resp) FALSE) |> req_perform() or req |> req_error(body = \(resp) resp_body_string(resp)) |> req_perform() to get more details from the error. Do you have any idea what kind of server you are connecting to? Like what tech stack it uses?
